# I have a cPickle error and does not know what he means maybe anyone know what this means?

Tags: python, pickle

I use a process communication RMC for which the code may be found below:

```
    HOST = ''     # local host
    PORT = 50000
    SERVER_ADDRESS = HOST, PORT

    # set up server socket
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        connFile = conn.makefile()
        name, args, kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)
        '''name = cPickle.load(connFile)
        args = cPickle.load(connFile)
        kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)'''
        res = _exportedMethods[name](*args,**kwargs)
        cPickle.dump(res,connFile) ; connFile.flush()
        conn.close()
```

This is the client site:

```
class RemoteFunction(object):
    def __init__(self,serverAddress,name):
        self.serverAddress = serverAddress
        self.name = name
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect(self.serverAddress)
        f = s.makefile()
        cPickle.dump((self.name, args, kwargs), f)
        '''cPickle.dump(self.name,f)
        cPickle.dump(args,f)     
        cPickle.dump(kwargs,f)'''   
        f.flush()
        res = cPickle.load(f)
        s.close()
        return res

def machine_changed_signal(machine):
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 50000
    SERVER_ADDRESS = HOST, PORT
    advise = RemoteFunction(SERVER_ADDRESS,'changes')
    advise(machine)
```

Upon execution, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manch011/disserver/src/disserver/gui/backends/receiver.py", line 71, in run
    args = cPickle.load(connFile)
cPickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

After my changes the new i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/manch011/disserver/src/disserver/gui/backends/receiver.py", line 69, in run
name, args, kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)
EOFError
```

I am not familiar with cPickle and hence cannot figure this one out, can someone explain it to me?

Thanks in advance
Chis

Answer (score 3):

When you transform your socket in a file-like object (`connFile = conn.makefile()`), everything you had in your socket is available in your file. When you do `cPickle.load(connFile)` the first time, everything that is in your socket/file is loaded by pickle, so on the second call, there isn't anything to unpickle, that's what pickle complain about when raising the exception.

All your data are unpickled at the first `cPickle.load(connFile)`, if you want to extract a function name, args and kwargs, try to send a tuple containing those data  :

Client-side :

```
cPickle.dump((function_name, args, kwargs), client_socket_as_file)
```

Server-side

```
name, args, kwargs = cPickle.load(connFile)
```

Comment: At first thank you for this answer. But the the socket changes if i call it on second so i need to load it again or not?

Comment: @Chris : if all your data are sent in one message on the client-side, you will receive it as one message on the client side (I edited my answer in this way).

Comment: yes but i will send more then one message with datas. i dont see the differents between yours and my code.:-( should i post my client site that u see the rest of my code?

Comment: @Chris try to change the client side as I specified in my answer. Only one dump to send everything in one "socket packet"

Comment: @Julien, i changed the client side as you specified but there is a new error i edited my question maybe you know howto handle it?

Comment: perhaps it is important to know that i will call the function machine_changed_signal(machine) many times.

Comment: @Chris : When I run the code you post (with an only modification in the `cPickle.dump((self.name, args, kwargs), f)`, replace name by self.name , it seems to work pretty well (even when calling many many times).

Comment: The machine object which I have to send got different variables. if i change only integer variables it works fine. but if i change a string variable i get one of the two error messages.:(

Comment: @Chris : it looks like a problem in your `machine` object, try to isolate/reproduce the problem (with only pickle/unpickle) and ask it in another related question.